# Why are appengine database keys sorted differently than strings

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine

I found this interesting, and am curious to know why db keys are ordered differently than strings ..

If you test the following example in the Python development environment (true for server as well), you will see the following (somewhat unexpected) behaviour

```
str1 = 'agpyb21hbmNlYXBwchILEglVc2VyTW9kZWwY4-agBgw'
str2 = 'agpyb21hbmNlYXBwchILEglVc2VyTW9kZWwYkoWBBQw'
```

Result: `str < str2` is `TRUE`

However, if we do the following

```
key1 = db.Key(str1)
key2 = db.Key(str2)
```

Result: `key1 < key2` is `FALSE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're comparing are string encoded keys, which have been passed through `base64` in order to be safe for output as text. Base64 does not preserve string ordering. If you decode them using `base64.urlsafe_b64decode`, they will compare in the order you expect.

Answer (score 2):

They use a different collation in extraction operator. I guess the db.Key() has strong probabilities to bind to DB properties.
So the < operator 'sees' different data, the first being (say) Ut8 source based, the second some weird db collation based, where the dash has specific meaning (unknown until we can get the specification). I've experienced some pain in the past feeding massive data across DB interfaces. But internationalization it's inherently complex.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with internationalization.

Comment: Don't guess when you can read the source. `Key` overloads `_cmp_` (in `google.appengine.api.datastore_types`) to do a comparison based on key components. It has nothing to do with internationalization.

Comment: Yes, my fault. I didn't realized the context. We had 'tears and blood' with a customer on a very similar data pattern, some years ago, but here it's simply OT